# OpsHub - Stopping and Restarting Migration

Tags: azure-devops, opshub

We have two migrations running through the OpsHub Visual Studio Online Migration Utility that have slowed down to what has seemed a halt.  Is there any way to tell if it is still running?  No changesets have moved within the past 3 hours. (only 25 moved on one project in one day).  If I were to stop the migration and restart it, will it continue from where it stopped or will it restart again and the past week and a half of migration is lost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were to **STOP** a running migration and re-start the same one after a while, it will continue from the point where it stopped. You will **not** lose any data in such situation.

What is the average no. of files involved in your normal change-set? Larger change-sets do take some time to migrate. You can refer the **OpsHubTFSService.log** file in the *installation-location/logs/* folder to intricately follow what the tool is currently doing in terms of processing data.